# Use only one method that accepts different typed parameters

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, generics, .net-3.5, casting

I've 3 different database tables that have the same 5 fields but those does not have any foreign key relation as they are not keeping the same value in fact, but the equivalents; like: CompanyA table has productA and CompanyB has productB.

so I have 3 different collections include 3 fields that are equivalent. So what I'd like to do is to use a single class that has companyType and ProductName properties and use only one method to cast those 3 different collections to one and only class object, say ResultClass.

```
public class ResultClass
{
    public EnumCompanyType CompanyType { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ResultClass> ConvertAnything(ICollection<T> collection)
    {
        //Cast it to ResultClass

        return resultClassCollection;
    }
}
```

So that I can use this like:

```
ICollection<ProductA> aCollection = GetCompanyAData();
ICollection<ProductB> bCollection = GetCompanyBData();        
ConvertAnything(aCollection);
ConvertAnything(bCollection);
```

I've tried "dynamic" but actually don't know the principle (neither have the knowledge); so I've messed it up and I think it's not for this stuff.

I've tried to create an extension method but since the extension has no type for its parameter (as it is using ICollection), I can't access the fields of the items (eg. properties)

I'm using LinqToSql and all the database table terms etc. belongs to this concept, nothing else.

edit:

I think I should made myself clear:
The multiple instances that I'm trying to avoid (or shouldn't I, still thinking) is like below

```
public ICollection<ResultClass> ConvertAnythingForA(ICollection<ProductA> collection)
    {
        foreach(var item in collection)
        {
            var result = new ResultClass
                             {
                                 ProductName = item.ProductA,
                                 ProductType = EnumProductType.ProductA
                             };

            resultClassCollection.Add(result);
        }
        return resultClassCollection;
    }

public ICollection<ResultClass> ConvertAnythingForB(ICollection<ProductB> collection)
    {
        foreach(var item in collection)
        {
            var result = new ResultClass
                             {
                                 ProductName = item.ProductB,
                                 ProductType = EnumProductType.ProductB
                             };

            resultClassCollection.Add(result);
        }
        return resultClassCollection;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may not be understanding you completely, but since ProductA, ProductB etc have the same signature it seems like you'd want an interface like

```
public interface IResultClass
{
    int CompanyType { get; set; }
    string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

And have those classes just implement the interface. You could work with collections of the interface that could have objects of the various types. If you need a convert anything method, it would look like

```
public ICollection<IResultClass> ConvertAnything<T>(ICollection<T> collection) where T : IResultClass
    {
        return collection.Select(x => (IResultClass)x).ToList();
    }
```

After comments- I see you that you are getting a non generic ICollection. Did you try something like this:

```
public ICollection<IResultClass> ConvertAnything(ICollection collection)
    {
        var x = collection.Cast<IResultClass>();
        return x.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried this as I explained in the question, but that way since it will be a generic, I can't access the properties; like collection[0].ProductName! And they don't have exactly same structure, they have differently named columns with equivalent values

Comment: That's the reason for the type constraint. If you constrain it to the interface, you can access anything defined in the interface.

Comment: so I guess this is not my solution?

Comment: in the edit you made, I couldn't understand how will it figure out how to cast it to IResultClass?

Comment: Cast<T> returns IEnumerable<T>, and will throw a runtime exception if it can't cast an item in the collection to T. So this would work if your product classes could all implement the same interface (or derive from the same base class).  (this cast method is just a shortcut- you could write your own code to do the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use function overloading. This example uses different numbers of parameters, but you could just as easily use different types instead.

http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/method-overloading/

Comment: that way, I don't create 3 exactly same methods but create a single method with exactly same trippled content, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

If both datasets are equivalent, why not just have one type called ICollection<Product>? And one function, eg. "GetProductData("A")", where "A"/"B" is the parameter? Or am I missing something?

Comment: they have equivalent fields and different fields as well, that's why they are not a single table.

Comment: Ok. You could create a single Product class that inherits interfaces for each type (eg. IProductA, IProductB, etc.). ConvertAnything would then have to figure out what to do for each product type. You could do this with overloading (so it knows what product type it is getting in advance). Or you code it to figure it out itself, and simply cast the Product to the appropriate type before conversion.